# Does npm's package audit use OWASP?

Tags: node.js, security, npm, owasp

Does npms internal `npm audit` command use the OWASP security standards when assessing packages for vulnerabilities?

Is there any background information on how npm's packages get audited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWASP security standards, as its name suggests, is only a compilation of standards security checks for web applications.

In fact, the `npm audit` command check for outdated dependencies or known issues. That command doesn't accomplish an audit on the fly. Security issues are raised from several sources, like [Node.js security team](https://nodejs.org/en/security/) or [Ubuntu security notices](https://usn.ubuntu.com/) for example, or by users like [you](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/security#security-point-of-contact).

Based on the information we have from npm, it's actually hard to tell if the [npm security team](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/security#internal-audits) in charge of evaluating packages vulnerabilities follow all the recommendations about security from OWASP organisation, but I'm sure a large part of it stays in their minds as security professionals.

Note that NPM also rely on Google cloud security scanner and AWS Penetration testing platform to evaluate security issues in packages.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but the [Node Audit Analyzer](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/analyzers/node-audit-analyzer.html) of the OWASP dependency-check toolset actually uses the NPM Audit API for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/173719309445/npm-audit-identify-and-fix-insecure) is a post from the npm blog that describes the `npm audit` command. I couldn't find any valid resource that describes how npm audits packages, but I think it might have a connection with The Node Security Platform.